# Can/Should you throw exceptions in a c# switch statement?

Tags: c#, exception, switch-statement, throw

I have an insert query that returns an int. Based on that int I may wish to throw an exception. Is this appropriate to do within a switch statement?

```
 switch (result)
        {

            case D_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                throw new ClientException(string.Format("D User Name: {0} , was not found.", dTbx.Text));
            case C_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                throw new ClientException(string.Format("C User Name: {0} , was not found.", cTbx.Text));
            case D_USER_ALREADY_MAPPED:
                throw new ClientException(string.Format("D User Name: {0} , is already mapped.", dTbx.Text));
            case C_USER_ALREADY_MAPPED:
                throw new ClientException(string.Format("C User Name: {0} , is already mapped.", cTbx.Text));
            default:

                break;
        }
```

I normally add break statements to switches but they will not be hit. Is this a bad design? Please share any opinions/suggestions with me.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Looks like you're trying to map return codes to exceptions. Your intention is clear so I'd say this solution is fine.

Answer (score 12):

Why not?

From *The C# Programming Language, Third Ed.* by Anders Hejlsberg et al, page 362:

> The statement list of a switch section typically ends in a `break`, `goto case`, or `goto default` statement, but any construct that renders the end point of the statement list unreachable is permitted. [...] Likewise, a `throw` or `return` statement always transfers control elsewhere and never reaches its end point.  Thus the following example is valid:
>
> ```
> switch(i) {
> case 0:
>     while(true) F();
> case 1:
>     throw new ArgumentException();
> case 2:
>     return;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

No problem... why would this be bad design?

Alternatively, since the exception type is the same in all `case`s, you could construct a lookup table for the error messages. That would save you some code duplication. For example:

```
static private Dictionary<int, string> errorMessages;
static
{
    // create and fill the Dictionary
}

// meanwhile, elsewhere in the code...
if (result is not ok) {
    throw new ClientException(string.Format(errorMessages[result], cTbx.Text, dTbx.Text));
}
```

In the messages themselves, you can select the appropriate parameter with `{0}`, `{1}`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really agree with your variable naming conventions ;), but I don't see why what you did would be inappropriate.  It seems like a fairly elegant way of translating an error from one medium to another.

I'm assuming that your "insert query" is some form of stored proc.

Answer (score 1):

If possible it would probably be better if you threw wherever the failed result is set, otherwise you end up with having to do both result checking and throwing. But might not be possible of course.

Also, I'd make your error strings into resources or constants with placeholders so that you don't have to change multiple places if you want to change the wording.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is OK. It seems like you are mapping an return code to an exception, using a switch statement. As long as there are not too many cases, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the approach you are taking.  Switch statements are a lot easier to read than if/then statements (and potentially faster too). The other thing you could do is load the possible exceptions in a

```
Dictionary<Result_Type, Exception>
```

and pull the exception from there.  If you have lots of switch statements this would make the code more compact (and you can add and remove them at runtime if you need to).

Comment: A dictionary might be good, but it would have to be a `Dictionary<Result_Type, Func<Exception>` or else something like  `Dictionary<Result_Type, ExceptionFactory>`, or `Dictionary<Result_Type, IExceptionFactory>`, with a suitably-defined exception-factory class (and interface, if applicable) defined somewhere.  Throwing an existing Exception object will at minimum destroy the stack trace.  If two threads both encounter the same sort of exception simultaneously, sharing an exception object between them could cause one thread's handler to see the other thread's stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, not the best example of using a dictionary for that.  If anything you'd need to probably store the exception type, and not the actual exception itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, storing the exception type isn't apt to be useful for much, since unless one uses Reflection (a somewhat-dodgy preposition in the context of an exception) there's no general way to, given an exception type, generate an exception of that type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with using a switch in your case.

The stronger consideration should go to whether exceptions themselves are appropriate. Generally, exceptions should be used only when a situation arises that is outside the bounds of expected behavior. Exceptions shouldn't be used as program flow logic. In your case you're probably okay to use them based on the code I see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I beg to differ from all the answers here..

Instead of having to switch in the code, I would rather pass in the `result` to the `ClientException` class & let it decide what string it needs to show rather then have an ugly switch all over the place to create various messages

My code would look like:

```
throw new ClientException(result, cTbx.Text);
```

So, even if you can throw errors in `switch...case`, you can avoid it all is my take

Comment: At which point the ClientException constructor would have same switch logic, but it would have to have breaks.

Comment: I downvoted because this "solution" just shifts the problem. This does not make any real difference.

Comment: @Seventh Element - you are right about not making any real difference, but in my solution the code is more maintainable in the sense that the switch...case is inside the ClientException class & the caller need not write the switch...case over & over in their code...

Comment: In addition to the point @Yishai makes, the result might not always be an error code.

Comment: @Rowland - in the case you mention, would an overload like: throw new ClientException("message"); help? I have seen the Exception class have various overloaded constructors & I think it is a good practice to do so...

Comment: @Sunny I mean cases when the result was success, and as you should only really throw exceptions in exceptional circumstances, throwing an exception along the lines of "It worked" would occur, without a prior `switch...case` or `if...else...`, which would kinda defeat the idea of pushing the actual string lookup elsewhere

Comment: @Rowland - in success cases, I am sure exceptions will not be thrown, my examples are for exception. I hope I am not mis-communicating in anyway about this.